# how to get the logs from adb logcat exactly as in run tab in Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, adb, logcat

I try to filter logs from `adb` to get the logs exactly like in Android studio. Tried to use `adb logcat | findstr com.example.package` but I can see anyway logs from the Android system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter all the logs coming from your app, my suggestion is to install [pidcat](https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat) and run it in the standard way such as:

```
pidcat your-package-name
```

This will allows you to filter out the app-related log entries in a nicely coloured way.

Comment: The key point is that i am developing my script in PyQT which runs the terminal in QProcess. Thats why i needed just a terminal command. Is there any command like ```findstr com.example.package``` which will sent the same logs as in run tab in Android studio?